# How to get sum of different columns in the same query in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I've implemented mysql query and is working fine but while converting / implementing it in Yii2 i'm facing some difficulties with active record .

```
SELECT 
COUNT(price) AS total,
SUM(IF(is_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS veg_count,
SUM(IF(is_not_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS non_veg_count
FROM order_table
```

I've tried doing following

```
orderTable::find()
  ->select('count(price) as total')
  ->sum(new Expression("IF(is_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)") => 'veg_count')
  ->sum(new Expression("IF(is_not_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)") => 'non_veg_count');
```

I'm getting following error:
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with "facing some difficulties", are you getting a error? If so, please edit your question to include the error message and the line the error refers to.

Comment: `'IF(is_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)'` quoting issues there - replace the outer ones with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a simple  select  using teh column in array
(and be careful for the correct quotes  sequence )

```
orderTable::find()
  ->select(['count(price) as total', 
    "SUM(IF(is_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS veg_count",
     "SUM(IF(is_not_veg = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS non_veg_count"])
```

but be sure you have the corresponding public var for the column alias otherwise your resulting models don't contain the result

in your OrderTable model  you need

```
class OrderTable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

  public $veg_count;  
  public $non_veg_count;       
  ...
```

Comment: i'm getting this error `Getting unknown property: app\models\orderTable::veg_count` @scaisEdge

Comment: thanks it works. I'm using this data in gridview, But the column names are not clickable. i.e, i'm not able to sort the data in ASC or DESC which is default behaviour. Can you please explain me. @scaisEdge

Comment: for this you must extend the related ModelSearch ..  you can see some sample in this tutorial  https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculatedrelated-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0

Comment: its always better to wrap `mysql` functions like `SUM` in the above inside the `new \yii\db\Expression()`

Comment: have tried it that way also check my question. that format is not working with multiple sum / aggregate queries.

Comment: @scaisEdge when i execute this aggregrate query, i'll be getting only one row of data. but gird view is showing something like `Showing 1-1 of 2,031 items.` any idea?